# Eloquent query not working Laravel 5.4

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have the following query and it is not working as expected.

```
$students = StudentStatus::with(['user.studentProgramme' => function ($query) {
                                $query->where('department_course_id', request('studyCourse'));
                            }], 'level', 'user.studentProgramme.course')
                            ->where('level_id', request('level'))
                            ->where('status', 0)
                            ->get();
```

The inner `WHERE`, that is `$query->where('department_course_id', request('studyCourse'))` is ignored and I don't know why.

Is there something I am missing out?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a scope issue try:

```
$studyCourse = ;

$students = StudentStatus::with(['user' => function($query) {
                            $query->with(['studentProgramme' => function ($query) {
                                $query->where('department_course_id', request('studyCourse'));
                            }]}], 'level', 'user.studentProgramme.course')
                            ->where('level_id', request('level'))
                            ->where('status', 0)
                            ->get();
```

Comment: I have checked if it is a scope issue and it was not. I `dd`ed `request('studyCourse')` and it gave me what it is expected, the selected value.

Comment: I think it may be the the way you have nested relations, see my edited answer. The syntax might be a tiny bit off.